# UWP Background task subscribes on event

Tags: c#, notifications, uwp, toast, background-task

I have an event FriendsOnlineEvent that invokes by server. 
When App is active this event works and I get toast notifications. 
How I can add this event to BackgroundTask and receive notifications when my app is closed?

```
   var longPollParams = await cache.vk.Messages.GetLongPollServer();
        var longPollClient = await cache.vk.StartLongPollClient(
             longPollParams.Server,
             longPollParams.Key,
             longPollParams.Ts
             );
        longPollClient.FriendOnlineEvent += LongPollClient_FriendOnlineEvent;
```

Comment: Don't use an image to show your code. Please change it to text.

Comment: @VijayNirmal I've edited

Answer (score 2):

You need to use push notifications, learn more here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/controls-and-patterns/tiles-and-notifications-windows-push-notification-services--wns--overview

Basically

1. Your app obtains a push channel and sends the push channel to your server
2. Your server stores all the push channels (mapped to the user or whatever)
3. When an event happens on the server that you want to send a toast for, your server sends a push notification to the push channels for the given user

Your push notification can simply be a toast that automatically appears without any code executing, or you can send a "raw notification" which wakes up your background task so that you can execute code and then show a toast from your app's code.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! But the server isn't mine. I want to use features that the server's pushes isn't provide.

Comment: Then you'll have to set up a periodic background task that runs as often as every 15 minutes, and then ask the server if there's something new when that background task runs. Read about using a [TimeTrigger periodic background task here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/run-a-background-task-on-a-timer-).

Alternatively if you aren't publishing your app to the Store, you can use [the restricted capability to run forever in the background](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/run-in-the-background-indefinetly).